# How to download a zip file and extract and parse xml file in it using PHP cURL

Tags: php, xml, curl, unzip

I have a script that usually download xml from an external server with a class.
Now I have with the same code download a zip file, unzip it and this is the xml to parse after.
My initial problem is how to retrieve a zip file unzip and take the xml?

This is my actual code:

```
    $ch2=curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_URL, $this->URL);
    curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 540);
    curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$this->XMLRequest);
    curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
    curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3); 
    curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

    $httpHeader2 = array(
        "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8",
        "Content-Encoding: UTF-8"
    );    

    $zip = curl_exec($ch2);
    $this->errno=curl_getinfo( $ch2, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE );

    curl_close($ch2);
```

How to get the zip file and unzip it to retrieve the xml inside?

Comment: Doesn't matter what kind of file it is - the download process will be IDENTICAL. You'll just have to add the unzip steps to get the xml file out of the zip.

Comment: I have print the value of $zip and is an encrypted string, well my var zip is already the zip file? I have to save into my server  unzip and then retrieve the xml inside? @MarcB

Comment: it's not an encrypted string, it's just the zipped data. You'll have to write it out to disk, unzip, and get the xml from that.

Comment: how save it in the right way? @MarcB

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    //Add  this to end of your code
    file_put_content('./temp.zip' ,$zip );
    $ZipArchive = new ZipArchive;
    if ($ZipArchive->open('./temp.zip' ) === TRUE) {
        $ZipArchive->extractTo('/my/destination/dir/');
        $ZipArchive->close();
        echo 'ok';
    } else {
        echo 'failed';
    }
?>
```